# Не работает плагин ProjectDjango для ide Eric-6

Tags: python, django

В Eric-6 после установки плагина ProjectDjango не появляется пункт выбора типа проекта "Проект Django", хотя должен. Перезапуск ide, переустановка плагина не помогли.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Попробуйте, может, другую версию питона выбрать, если там есть такая возможность. И в чекбоксах разные варианты рассмотрите. Если нет - перезагружаете систему и смотрите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Связался с автором плагина. Вот перевод его ответа:

> Здравствуйте, прежде чем тип проекта Django станет доступен, нужно выполнить несколько вещей.
>
> 1. Плагин Django должен быть активным. Это можно проверить в диалоге информации о плагине.
> 2. Использование Django должно быть настроено. Это можно сделать на странице «Django» диалогового окна конфигурации. Здесь вы должны
>    настроить виртуальную среду Python, содержащую пакет Django (то
>    есть, содержащую исполняемый файл администратора Django
>    `django-admin`). Это должно быть сделано для каждого варианта Python,
>    для которого вы хотите разработать.
>
> После этого тип проекта должен быть доступен.

После указанных манипуляций все заработало. Что именно делал:

1. С помощью конфигуратора виртуального окружения, создал виртуальное же окружение.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Активируем созданное вирутальное окружение и устанавливаем Django
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В окне настроек выбираем соответствующее окружение
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. При создании проекта появляется желаемый пункт с типом проекта
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]